# Inline SVG to jvectormap

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jvectormap

I have to customize a map to use it in jvector map. So I use inline `SVG` to make a map. The map shows perfectly but I can't manage to manipulate it using jvectormap. I'm just a beginner in jvectormap so maybe my code is a bit error. Please if you have any ideas, any answer is accepted.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code anyway:

```
<div id="pantsun" >
<svg title="well" width="500" height="300" style="border: 1px solid #000;background-color: lightgreen;" >
  <rect x="200" y="0" width="30" height="300" style="fill:white;" />
  <rect x="0" y="50" width="500" height="30" style="fill:white;" />
  <rect x="0" y="150" width="500" height="30" style="fill:white;" />
  <rect x="10" y="18" width="30" height="30" style="fill:darkgrey;" />
  <rect x="45" y="18" width="30" height="30" style="fill:darkgrey;" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
  </svg>
</div>

<script>

$(function(){
 $('#pantsun').vectorMap({
  map: 'well',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  markers: [{
    coords: [0, 50],
    name: 'well 1',
    style: {fill: 'white'}
  },{
    coords: [0, 150],
    name: 'well 2',
    style: {fill: 'white'}
}}};

</script>
```

What I'm trying to do is in this [link.](http://jvectormap.com/examples/mall/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you're passing to vectorMap and the `markers` array inside it are mal-formed with missing brackets and closures. If you organize the code indentation, this kind of thing is easy to spot.

The documentation and examples are not very good. Here's [how to solve the `jvm is not defined` error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681764/1287812) that I found while testing your code (and that happens in one of their sample files).

Also, the [Mall example that you cite](http://jvectormap.com/examples/mall/) does not mention the need to [load a `mall-map.js`](http://jvectormap.com/js/mall-map.js) (`well-map.js` in your case). It produces this error in your code:

> Uncaught Error: Attempt to use map which was not loaded: well

Here's the code I tested, the map doesn't render anything meaningful, as I tested with `mall-map.js`, but there are no JS errors being thrwon...

```
<script src="assets/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery-jvectormap.js"></script>
<script src="mall-map.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#pantsun').vectorMap({
        map: 'mall',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        markers: [
            { coords: [0, 50], name: 'well 1', style: {fill: 'white'} },
            { coords: [0, 150], name: 'well 2', style: {fill: 'white'} }
        ] // <-- missing
    });  // <-- mal formed
});     // <-- mal formed
</script>
```