# jvm.Map is not a function IN JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make this graph from this url
http://jvectormap.com/examples/usa-unemployment/

I am getting error is this 
**jvm.Map is not a function**

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/EHPsa2nUxxprs1tM0OoP?p=preview

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
        var val = 2009;
        statesValues = jvm.values.apply({}, jvm.values(data.states)),
        metroPopValues = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], jvm.values(data.metro.population)),
        metroUnemplValues = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], jvm.values(data.metro.unemployment));

        $('#world-map-gdp').vectorMap({
            map: 'us_aea_en',
            markers: data.metro.coords,
            series: {
                markers: [{
                    attribute: 'fill',
                    scale: ['#FEE5D9', '#A50F15'],
                    values: data.metro.unemployment[val],
                    min: jvm.min(metroUnemplValues),
                    max: jvm.max(metroUnemplValues)
                }, {
                    attribute: 'r',
                    scale: [5, 20],
                    values: data.metro.population[val],
                    min: jvm.min(metroPopValues),
                    max: jvm.max(metroPopValues)
                }],
                regions: [{
                    scale: ['#DEEBF7', '#08519C'],
                    attribute: 'fill',
                    values: data.states[val],
                    min: jvm.min(statesValues),
                    max: jvm.max(statesValues)
                }]
            },
            onMarkerTipShow: function (event, label, index) {
                label.html(
                    '<b>' + data.metro.names[index] + '</b><br/>' +
                    '<b>Population: </b>' + data.metro.population[val][index] + '</br>' +
                    '<b>Unemployment rate: </b>' + data.metro.unemployment[val][index] + '%');
            },
            onRegionTipShow: function (event, label, code) {
                label.html(
                    '<b>' + label.html() + '</b></br>' +
                    '<b>Unemployment rate: </b>' + data.states[val][code] + '%');
            }
        });

        var mapObject = $('#world-map-gdp').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');

        $("#slider").slider({
            value: val,
            min: 2005,
            max: 2009,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                val = ui.value;
                mapObject.series.regions[0].setValues(data.states[ui.value]);
                mapObject.series.markers[0].setValues(data.metro.unemployment[ui.value]);
                mapObject.series.markers[1].setValues(data.metro.population[ui.value]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you actually download and reference the thevectormap.js script? jvm.Map is not a default jQuery function.

Comment: I downloaded and import on plunker pls check plunker

Comment: Are you sure your script has access to the vector map script? I can see you reference it from dropbox. Did you try downloading the script, adding it to your project folder and reference it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Need to import four js files:

- jvectormap/jvectormap.js (binds/registers **jvm**, but also with jQuery: **jvm.$ = jQuery**)
- **jvectormap/src/map.js**  (creates **jvm.Map** constructor)
- jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.js  (add **.vectorMap** as a JQuery plugin **$.fn.vectorMap** and registers 'addMap' or 'set' callbacks, for a later world map registration/update: e.g 'world_mill'), useful on Ajax requests when map data is loaded after.
- jvectormap-maps/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill.js

If using bower (*bower.json*), these were the latest packages:

```
    "jvectormap": "2.0.5",
    "jvectormap-maps": "*"
```

Comment: Absolute lifesaver! 2 years later but this fixed my problem