# Getting a "jvm.Map is not a constructor" for jvectormap

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

I'm trying to use jvectormap in a grails application and have been following the examples on the jvectormap website to get started.  However, I cannot figure out why I'm getting the error that "jvm.Map is not a constructor".  I included all the necessary .css and .js files, and the code is pretty much verbatim from jvectormap's website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <asset:stylesheet src="jquery-jvectormap-2.0.1.css"/>
        <asset:javascript src="jquery-jvectormap-2.0.1.min.js"/>
        <asset:javascript src="jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"/>    

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="widthholder"><span></span></div>
        <div id="world-map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
        <script>
            var gdpData = {
                "AF": 16.63,
                "AL": 11.58,
                "DZ": 158.97
            };          

            $(function(){
                map = new jvm.Map({
                    map: 'world_mill_en',
                    container: $('#world-map'),
                    series: {
                        regions: [{
                            values: gdpData,
                            scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
                            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
                        }]
                    },
                    onRegionTipShow: function(e, el, code){
                      el.html(el.html()+' (GDP - '+gdpData[code]+')');
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer is here 
http://jvectormap.com/tutorials/data-visualization/

```
var mapObject = $('.map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
```

Comment: Please, check my comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775873/jvm-map-is-not-a-function-in-jquery/63617366#63617366