# "Cannot read property of undefined" - jvectormap

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have a code like that:

```
    var dataVal = {
  "PL-WP": 'red'
}

var map = $('#map').vectorMap({map: 'pl_merc',
  backgroundColor:'#c9c9c9',
  zoomOnScroll:false,
  series: {
    regions: [{
      scale: {
        'red': 'red',
        'blue': 'blue'
      },
      attribute: 'fill',
      values: dataVal
    }]
  },
  onRegionClick(e,code) {
    dataVal[code] = 'blue';
    map.series.regions['values'].setValues(dataVal);
  }
});
```

The goal of last line of that snippet is dynamic changing "values" property. Unfortunately, code doesn't work and provides bug "Cannot read property "regions" of undefined". Is any way to solve it?

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BcQo.png)

Comment: Please, check my comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775873/jvm-map-is-not-a-function-in-jquery/63617366#63617366

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get undefined is because `var map` object is a jquery object. so when you use `map.series` it doesn't have that attribute and it is undefined. Try to console out map.data() and see if vectorMap adds any object prop to DOM node. So you can access to that